# Converting UTC Timestamp to user time zone

Tags: java

In my PostgreSQL database i have a `Timestamp` column where I store data in UTC,

I fetch this date as `LocalDateTime` in my Java code.

When I generate an excel file I want to convert this date to the user time zone,

I found this solution:

```java
localDateTimeFromDB.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)
                   .atZone(ZoneId.of(userTimeZone))
                   .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")));
```

It works but I want to know if is it the optimize solution ?

Comment: Is `localDateTimeFromDb` actually a `LocalDateTime`?

Comment: Yes it's a `LocalDateTime`

Comment: @Youssef - Your solution is already optimized and good.

Answer (score 0):

You could skip the *manual* imtermediate conversion to an `Instant`, but I doubt this will optimize your approach significantly.

Here's some slightly different code of a very similar length producing the same result (,I think. You haven't shown yours so far):

```java
localDateTimeFromDb.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)
                   .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of(userTimeZone))
                   .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
```

Comment: if I skip `toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)` it wouldn't apply the correct time zone

Comment: @Youssef - There is nothing wrong with this solution. It will produce the same result as yours.